# SQL Script grouping all data by OrderNo?

Tags: sql

I have multiple tables I'm joining. I'm trying to get data to group by the OrderNo. My results are duplicating rows.  How can I get my results to all roll up to OrderNo?

```
SELECT     
tractor.id as Unit,
tractor.type_of,
orders.id as OrderNo, 
billing_history.delivery_date, 
orders.total_charge,
Case when movement.loaded = 'L' then movement.move_distance else 0 end as LoadedMiles,
Case when movement.loaded = 'E' then movement.move_distance else 0 end as EmptyMiles,  
billing_history.distance, 
billing_history.linehaul_chg, 
billing_history.other_charge, 
billing_history.total_charges, 
OrderPay, 
PerDiemPay,
TotalPay
from tractor

Left join billing_history 
on billing_history.tractor_id = tractor.id

Left join orders 
ON billing_history.order_id = orders.id

Left join 
(Select drs_settle_hist.order_id,   
sum(drs_settle_hist.order_pay) as OrderPay, 
sum(drs_settle_hist.perdiem_pay) as PerDiemPay, 
sum(drs_settle_hist.total_pay) as TotalPay
from drs_settle_hist 
where drs_settle_hist.is_void = 'N' 
group by 
drs_settle_hist.order_id) 
drs_settle_hist on orders.id = drs_settle_hist.order_id

Left join movement_order 
on billing_history.order_id = movement_order.order_id

Left join movement 
on movement_order.movement_id = movement.id


WHERE     orders.ordered_date  between '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59.000'
and billing_history.delivery_date between '2014-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31         23:59:59.000' 
and tractor.type_of is not null
```

Here is a sample of the data:
[image]

What results should look like:
[image]

Comment: How do you want these yellow-painted rows to look like after you roll them up? For example, what will be the value of LoadedMiles or EmptyMiles columns? You can post a sample result showing your expected output.

Comment: Your result doesnt have duplicated row, each row with same OrderId as different values in other colums, so you cannot merge them together.

Comment: @AlexDeb - yes they are duplicated rows.  It is the Same Order number, total charges, linehaul, other, total, orderpay, perdiempay, totalpay.  The only thing that is different is the Empty Miles and Loaded Miles.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Distinct keyword may work for you like Distinct (orders.id).

Comment: thank you for your response. Distinct doesn't work. It is duplicating rows because of all the joined tables. I'm a new SQL user so I'm sure there are experts out there that know how to do this. :)

Answer (score -1):

You are only grouping the subselect in the join. Try grouping the full query:

```
SELECT     
tractor.id as Unit,
tractor.type_of,
orders.id as OrderNo, 
billing_history.delivery_date, 
orders.total_charge,
Case when movement.loaded = 'L' then movement.move_distance else 0 end as LoadedMiles,
Case when movement.loaded = 'E' then movement.move_distance else 0 end as EmptyMiles,  
billing_history.distance, 
billing_history.linehaul_chg, 
billing_history.other_charge, 
billing_history.total_charges, 
OrderPay, 
PerDiemPay,
TotalPay
from tractor

Left join billing_history 
on billing_history.tractor_id = tractor.id

Left join orders 
ON billing_history.order_id = orders.id

Left join 
(Select drs_settle_hist.order_id,   
sum(drs_settle_hist.order_pay) as OrderPay, 
sum(drs_settle_hist.perdiem_pay) as PerDiemPay, 
sum(drs_settle_hist.total_pay) as TotalPay
from drs_settle_hist 
where drs_settle_hist.is_void = 'N' 
group by 
drs_settle_hist.order_id) 
drs_settle_hist on orders.id = drs_settle_hist.order_id

Left join movement_order 
on billing_history.order_id = movement_order.order_id

Left join movement 
on movement_order.movement_id = movement.id


WHERE     orders.ordered_date  between '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59.000'
and billing_history.delivery_date between '2014-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31         23:59:59.000' 
and tractor.type_of is not null

group by OrderNo
```

Comment: @yalpertem - results sample added

Comment: your suggestion doesn't work as it gives me a series of items in the select list which are not contained in the aggregate function or group by clause - argh!